# modal close not work

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-redux

modal opens but does not close...

When using alert this.state.visibleModal is false, but modal is still open...

```
output =
      <Modal
        animationType = {"none"}
        transparent = {false}
        visible={this.state.visibleModal}
        onRequestClose = {() => { this.toggleModal(!this.state.visibleModal) } }
      >
        <View style = {styles.modalBackground}>
          <Text>
            hello
          </Text>

          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress = {()=> {
              this.toggleModal(!this.state.visibleModal)
            }}
          >
            <Text>close</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>

        </View>
      </Modal>

    this.setState({output:output})
```

Function related to toggleModal:

```
toggleModal(visible){
    this.setState({visibleModal:visible})
  }
```

render function related to program:

```
render() {
 return (
      <View style={styles.MainContainer}>

        <TextInput
          ref="mobileField"
          style={styles.input}
          autoCorrect={false}
          onChangeText={this.handleMobile}
        >
        </TextInput>

        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.submitButton}
          onPress={
            ()=>this.editMe(this.state.mobile)
          }
        >
        <Text style={styles.submitButtonText}>edit</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <View>{this.state.output}</View>

      </View>
    );
  }
```

please help me to fix the problem...

thanks..

Comment: Can you show your `render` function?

Comment: Please show code your `Modal` component

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't store the React DOM element in the state just store the `visible` flag in state

```
render() {
 return (
      <View style={styles.MainContainer}>

        <TextInput
          ref="mobileField"
          style={styles.input}
          autoCorrect={false}
          onChangeText={this.handleMobile}
        >
        </TextInput>

        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.submitButton}
          onPress={
            ()=>this.editMe(this.state.mobile)
          }
        >
        <Text style={styles.submitButtonText}>edit</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <View>
          <Modal
        animationType = {"none"}
        transparent = {false}
        visible={this.state.visibleModal}
        onRequestClose = {() => { this.toggleModal(!this.state.visibleModal) } }
      >
        <View style = {styles.modalBackground}>
          <Text>
            hello
          </Text>

          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress = {()=> {
              this.toggleModal(!this.state.visibleModal)
            }}
          >
            <Text>close</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>

        </View>
      </Modal>
        </View>

      </View>
    );
  }
```